# Thingsboard Upgradation failed from version 2.5.1 to2.5.2 for cassandra

Tags: windows, cassandra, thingsboard

I am getting this error on windows:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to upgrade Cassandra database, unsupported fromVersion: 2.5.0
at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.CassandraTsDatabaseUpgradeService.upgradeDatabase(CassandraTsDatabaseUpgradeService.java:52)
at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:146)
at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
ThingsBoard upgrade failed!

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted indicates that you ran the upgrade script with a `fromVersion` of `2.5.0` which leads to this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to upgrade Cassandra database, unsupported fromVersion: 2.5.0
```

A quick check of `CassandraTsDatabaseUpgradeService.java` confirms that the only supported `fromVersion` is `2.4.3` (see [source code here](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/v2.5.2/application/src/main/java/org/thingsboard/server/service/install/CassandraTsDatabaseUpgradeService.java)):

```
public void upgradeDatabase(String fromVersion) throws Exception {
    switch (fromVersion) {
        case "2.4.3":
        ...
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to upgrade Cassandra database, unsupported fromVersion: " + fromVersion);
    }
}
```

According to the [ThingsBoard v2.5.2 upgrade instructions](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/upgrade-instructions/#upgrading-to-252), the full command is:

```
$ sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/upgrade.sh --fromVersion=2.4.3
```

Comment: Yes, I am using upgrade.bat --fromVersion=2.4.3 command only